# Can two Server 2016 Essentials at different offices be connected to the same Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, windows-server-2016

We're currently having a setup where we have to different domains, and two different offices and nothing is shared what so ever.

Planning our next upgrade we're thinking of merging the Office 365 organisations, and simply add both domains (a.com and b.com) to all users so they can receive emails on both organisations.

Given that we would use Server 2016 Essentials at both locations, would it be possible to setup them individually with no connection inbetween, but still connected to the same Office 365 account, so that a user that visits the other office can sign on using their normal account?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, one Office 365 tenant may have multiple forests. However, if you are planning to achive single sign-on (SSO) within a whole environment, you then need to synchronize both AD's. This can be done with Azure AD Sync (AFAIK DirSync doesnt support the synchronization from multiple forests).

Comment: I'm not sure we want forests. We just want a flat organisation, where all users are in the same directory under the same organisation. Is that correct? We just want to use two Server 2016 Essentials server connected to the same Office 365, and I'm not sure if that's supported.

Comment: Yes, Essentials 2016 edition supports Office 365 integration, so you can easily add your servers to the single tenant. This might help: http://www.itpromentor.com/essentials-aad-365/